# rails, pg exception from sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, pg

please help resolve issue with

Message
PG::UnableToSend: server closed the connection unexpectedly This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request.
Traceback
 PG::UnableToSend: server closed the connection unexpectedly
       This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.

full log: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/igorkasyanchuk/cc96dba31b0b0f83b77faadf077433e8/raw/70af94105b0a7649b6ad0dde086ac539902d1d3f/gistfile1.txt

sample code:

```
class RedZoneCrossedWorker < Worker
  def perform(event_id)
    Chewy.strategy(:atomic) do
      puts "#{self.class.name} Performing: #{event_id} #{jid}"
      event = RedZoneCrossedShipmentEvent.find_by(id: event_id)
      shipment = event.try(:shipment)
      if shipment
        # generate driver/oo payments
        shipment.generate_red_zone_payments
        # send mails and notifications if red zone crossed successfully
        notifier = event.successfully_completed? ? 'ShipmentNotifiers::ShipmentRedZoneSuccessNotifier' : 'ShipmentNotifiers::ShipmentRedZoneViolationsNotifier'
        ShipmentNotificationWorker.new.perform(event.shipment_id, notifier)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

we have 2 app servers + 1 db. we have pool 25 and workers 20, rails, sidekiq, pg.

it happen only with sidekiq background workers.

thanks for advices

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Here we expect you to put all the relevant details into your question. We don't want to go look offsite for details. We also need to see the relevant snippets of code. here's an article on how to ask a question (such that you're likely to actually get a helpful answer): http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you using launchy or letter opener gem ?

Comment: What is the size of the connection pool of your pg server?

Comment: launchy and letter opener - no

Comment: which pool exactly you asking? from database.yml? we have pool: 20

Answer (score 0):

Looks like problem was solved using:

```
production:
  ....
  pool: 20
  variables:
    tcp_keepalives_idle: 60
    tcp_keepalives_interval: 60
    tcp_keepalives_count: 100
```